# iOS Screen recording detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscreen

I tried to detect if screen capture is on for the application for iOS 11, to detect this the `UIScreen.mainScreen.isCaptured` property is used to check if it is recorded.

It works fine for the first launch, when the app is terminated and launched again, then the API returns NO though the screen capture is on.

**Code:**

```
//In viewWillAppear block

__block ViewController *weakSelf = self;
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
    [weakSelf screenCaptureDetection];
  }];

- (void) screenCaptureDetection {
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    for (UIScreen *screen in [UIScreen screens]) {
      if([screen performSelector:@selector(isCaptured)]){
      //Detected YES
    }
  }
}
```

**Use case scenario:**

1. Launch the app
2. Start screen recorder using the apple screen recording option
3. The screen recorder is detected
4. Terminate the app
5. Repeat the step 1 and 2
6. The screen recording is not detected, the API `UIScreen.mainScreen.isCaptured` returns NO

Please suggest

Comment: If that's reproducible, have you considered filing a [bugreport](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/)?

Comment: Yes it is reproducible

Comment: FYI, unless you're still using MRR you should use `__weak` instead of `__block`. When using ARC, `__block` variables are still retained by the block. Also, `__weak` gives you a zeroing weak reference, which probably is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Lukas I will make the change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for recording repeatedly.

I used this code and it worked for me.
check it out:

https://gist.github.com/abhimuralidharan/8db55dff9023028867b719f251372bd7#file-screenrecordingdetector-m

Comment: Yes, I am using the NSTimer to repeat the check for every 2 seconds